# SO_RCVTIMEO timeout value is not taking effect in recv_from API

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets, recvfrom

I tried to use SO_RCVTIMEO option to timeout when there is no data in recvfrom API. But this is not taking effect, and the code is stuck when there is no data from the source.

I even tried using recv instead of recvfrom. Still the same issue.

Please let me know if anything is missing in my code.

```
int sock_r=socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL)); 
if(sock_r<0)
{
    printf("open_raw_socket(): error in opening the socket");
    return -1;
}

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec =  0;
int ret = setsockopt(sock_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
perror("error: ");

socklen_t ntrcv, ntsnd; 
struct timeval trcv;   
ntrcv = sizeof(struct timeval); 
if (getsockopt(sock_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &trcv, &ntrcv) < 0) 
{
    perror("2");
    TF_MSG("error");
}  

while(1)
{
    saddr_len=sizeof saddr;
    recv_len = recvfrom(sock_r,buffer,buflen,0,&saddr,(socklen_t *)&saddr_len);


    if(recv_len<=0)
    {
        printf("error in reading recvfrom function");
        return 0;
    }
.....
```

Comment: Don't call `perror()` unless there *was* an error, e.g. at `setsockopt()`, and *do* call it if there was, e.g. at `socket()` and `recvfrom()`. *Was* there an error? And what was the value in `trcv` returned by `getsockopt()`?

Comment: i changed the perror() as mentioned. Only if setsockopt() is returning value < 0, perror() is added. trcv was returning correct value. Both seconds and usec were holding the correct value. Just that it was not taking any effect

Comment: Rather than using `SO_RCVTIMEO` at all, you can use `select()`/`(e)poll()` with a timeout to wait for data to arrive before then calling `recv/from()` to read it

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau, I tried the below code. In this attempt, no data was received even when other side pumps the data.

struct pollfd fd;
  int ret;
  
  fd.fd = sock_r; // your socket handler 
  fd.events = POLLIN;
  ret = poll(&fd, 1, 1000); // 1 second for timeout
  switch (ret) {
      case -1:
         printf("ret value for poll : -1");
         break;
      case 0:
    printf("ret value for poll : 0");
          break;
      default:
          recv_len = recv(sock_r,buffer,buflen, 0 ); // get your data
          break;
  }